# Angular external template in modal

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using Ng-Bootstrap Modal with auxiliary routing in Angular to display auxiliary routes in modal window. For example on main screen user clicks on customer and app displays customer details in modal window.

```
<ng-template #proxyRouteModalContent>
    <div class="modal-body proxy-modal-body">
        <router-outlet
            (activate)="onRouterOutletActivate($event)"
        ></router-outlet>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

```
@ViewChild('proxyRouteModalContent')
modalContent: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.modalInstance = this.modalService.open(this.modalContent, {
        size: this.size,
        scrollable: true,
   });
}
```

All works great. When a modal window is opened, angular render content to , user sees nice modal window.

Problem started when I need to render  first, read some properties from component and then open modal window using this properties. For example, I am displaying CustomerDetailComponent in modal window and CustomerDetailComponent has a property `size: 'lg' | 'xl' = 'xl' which says modal window should render to 'xl' size.

So, I am trying to figure out how to render  outside  and then "inject" it into modal window.

How can I do this?